# In a Google Spreadsheet Gadget, how to write to the spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a gadget to be embedded in a Google Spreadsheet. Reading data using the visualization API (i.e. google.visualization.QueryResponse object) works fine, however I also need to amend some data in the spreadsheet from within the gadget.

Though having searched for it for a while, I have not found a way to do that. Does anybody know how I can modify a spreadsheet from within a gadget (basically Javascript running inside the spreadsheet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue('your value');
```